# how to print tab separated values of a python list of strings specifying a maximum line length and avoiding string break

Tags: python, list, printing, output, tabulate

I am trying to write a function that takes dir(obj) as argument and prints out a perfect list of string tabbed in multiple columns. dir(obj) is a function that generates a list of strings where each string is a method available for the chosen obj. The output, however, is formatted as a single column. I would like to generate tabbed columns instead.

So far I managed to use

```
lst = dir(str) # naming the variable as lst and trying it out with 'str' object    
print(*lst, sep='         \t') # note the amount of white spaces before \t
```

However, no matter how many times I tried separating them with different quantities of white space (sep='     \t'), the columns always break at some point. Please see below a screen clip from my Jupyter notebook:

[image: screen clip from Jupyter notebook]

I've spend the whole afternoon trying different alternatives, including [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html), [columnar](https://pypi.org/project/columnar/) and [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/), but these modules seem to work better with tables. Thus far I have not found a simpler and obvious way to do such a simple and obvious task. what am I missing here, please?

Comment: That is the object I am using in Python to list the directory of methods available.  str turns an int (integer) type into a string, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
longest = max([len(l) for l in lst])
cols = 5
padding = 5

for i, a in enumerate(lst):
    print(a, end=" "*(longest-len(a)+padding) if (i+1) % cols else "\n")
```

will produce a result that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMh3d.png)

" "*(longest-len(a)+padding) will adjust the columns for the longest variable and add some extra padding.

Comment: I think this is an awesome solution! I don't see why not turn into a builtin print method implementation in Python3.future. Those standar dir outputs are hard in the eyes. Thank you.